# Pin fur-planes to object

Tags: objects, parent

Is it possible to pin an object (lots of planes of fur) to, say a wolf, and make them move independently of each other(have them follow the part of the object they touch)? Or will I have to change all the planes to individual objects?

Comment: In which way they will be "touched"? You are talking about a hair simulation, a physic simulation, or is this a modeling question?

Comment: Sorry, but you would need to make them individual objects.

Comment: Would hair particles do something like what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No. I need to use the model in UE4, and from what I've found, UE4 doesn't support Blenders hair particle system. Thankyou though.